# Tennis balls counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

On a Friday morning, the pro shop of a tennis club has 14 identical cans of tennis balls. If they are all sold by Sunday night and we are interested only in how many were sold in each day, in how many different ways could the tennis balls have been sold on Friday, Saturday and Sunday?

What I think about the problem:

Let $a$ denote the number of cans sold on Friday.

Let $b$ denote the number of cans sold on Saturday.

Let $c$ denote the number of cans sold on Sunday.

We seek the number of ordered triples of the form $(a,b,c)$ on the condition that the triple satisfies the following:

1) $a,b,c$ are non-negative integers

2) $a+b+c=14$

Thanks in advance

Comment: You only need to figure out how many are sold on Friday and Saturday, since the remainder are sold on Sunday. There are up to 14 cans sold on Friday and Saturday. So how many ways can you split numbers up to 14 between two days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to the [stars and bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29):

For natural numbers $n$ and $k,$ the number of distinct $n$-tuples (in our case, how many triples, with $n = 3$) of non-negative integers whose sum is $k$ (in this case, k = 14) is given by the binomial coefficient $$\binom{n + k - 1}{k} = \binom{3 + 14 - 1}{14} = \binom{16}{14} = \binom{16}{2}$$

Comment: It depends what you denote as $n$ and $k$. If we put $n = 14, k=3$ instead, then we have $$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1} = \binom{16}{2} = \binom{n+k-1}{n}$$ and as we see, whatever assignment we make to $n, k$, the number of such combinations for $a, b, c$ is equal to $\binom{1}{2}$

Comment: Another TU +1....